# How to Suppress/Ignore(/Fix) matplotlib Axes3D ValueError?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, suppress-warnings, mplot3d

As requested, here's the minimum, working example (below); my apologies that it's so much, but this seems to be an issue that requires overhead structure (specifically the presence of the 2d and 3d axes on two separate tabs at once, but not when 3d or 2d is alone):

```
import sys, os
pyDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) #python file location

from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
#matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1
import matplotlib.path as pltPath
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib import rc
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


class P4(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(P4, self).__init__(parent)
        P4.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        P4.layout.setContentsMargins(20,20,20,20)
        P4.layout.setSpacing(10)

        P4.button_pic1 = QtGui.QPushButton('View Plots', self)
        P4.button_pic1.clicked.connect(self.RC_vid1)
        P4.layout.addWidget(P4.button_pic1, 2, 8, 1, 1)
        P4.button_pic1.show()

    def RC_vid1(self):

        global PrD_window
        try:
            PrD_window.close()
        except:
            pass

        PrD_window = PrD_Viz()
        PrD_window.show()

################################################################################

class PrD_Viz(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PrD_Viz, self).__init__()
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        vid_tab2 = ManifoldCanvas(self)
        vid_tab3 = PsiCanvas(self)
        global vid_tabs
        vid_tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        vid_tabs.addTab(vid_tab2, 'Plot 1')
        vid_tabs.addTab(vid_tab3, 'Plot 2')

        style = """QTabWidget::tab-bar{
                alignment: center;
                }"""
        self.setStyleSheet(style)
        self.setCentralWidget(vid_tabs)
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal) #freezes out parent window
        self.show()

class ManifoldCanvas(QtGui.QDialog):
    pts_orig = []

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ManifoldCanvas, self).__init__(parent)

        self.figure = Figure(dpi=200)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.figure.set_tight_layout(True)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        x=[1,5,9]
        y=[2,6,10]

        ManifoldCanvas.pts_orig = zip(x,y)
        for i in ManifoldCanvas.pts_orig:
            x,y = i
            self.ax.scatter(x,y,s=1,c='#1f77b4')

        self.canvas.draw_idle()

        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar, 0,0,1,5)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 1,0,1,5)

        self.setLayout(layout)

class PsiCanvas(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PsiCanvas, self).__init__(parent)

        self.psi1 = [10,11,12]
        self.psi2 = [24,19,18]
        self.psi3 = [99,90, 105]

        # create canvas and plot data:
        self.figure = Figure(dpi=200)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.ax = Axes3D(self.figure)
        self.ax.mouse_init()

        self.ax.scatter(self.psi1, self.psi2, self.psi3, label='psi_dif', linewidths= .5, edgecolors='k', c='#d62728') #C3

        self.canvas.draw_idle() #refresh canvas

        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar, 0,0,1,4)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 1,0,4,4)

        self.setLayout(layout)

################################################################################
# overhead GUI control: 

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        tab4 = P4(self)

        global tabs
        tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        tabs.resize(250,150)

        tabs.addTab(tab4, 'Eigenfunctions')

        self.setCentralWidget(tabs)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The plot behaves perfectly on linux and macOS (with no warnings on macOS), but on linux, I'm getting this dreadful paragraph of errors each time the plot is shown in the GUI (which ends up polluting the terminal):

```
/data/ees/anaconda/envs/manifold/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axis3d.py:270: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  ax_scale = self.axes.bbox.size / self.figure.bbox.size
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/ees/anaconda/envs/manifold/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 176, in __draw_idle_agg
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/data/ees/anaconda/envs/manifold/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 474, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/data/ees/anaconda/envs/manifold/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/ees/anaconda/envs/manifold/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1159, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/data/ees/anaconda/envs/manifold/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 290, in draw
    ax.draw(renderer)
  File "/data/ees/anaconda/envs/manifold/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axis3d.py", line 288, in draw
    self.label.draw(renderer)
  File "/data/ees/anaconda/envs/manifold/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/ees/anaconda/envs/manifold/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 757, in draw
    raise ValueError("posx and posy should be finite values")
ValueError: posx and posy should be finite values
```

I'd like to either suppress this error or fix it; any advice would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: The error `ValueError: posx and posy should be finite values` means that one of those values is ending up at *infinity*. I would try adjusting the dpi and padding/offsets, or removing parts to try and localise the issue.

Comment: The `backend_qt5agg` error is not an issue as that code is used by both 4 & 5 backends.

Comment: @mfitzp Thank you; I've edited my post above to remove any excess (including all padding, etc), and gotten rid of the `dpi=200`; this is now the bare-bones, and yet the error still remains. What else should I investigate?

Comment: Thanks, that's great. If it's still happening with this there must be something about your data that calculates differently on the two platforms. Are you using the same version of Python on each? Can you check the values of `psi1`, `psi2` and `psi3` on Linux for presence of `inf` or `inf-` values?

Comment: Does the same happen if you replace `self.canvas.draw_idle()` by `self.canvas.draw()`? How exactly do you run your code? (In the console, in an IDE?) How do you call `PsiCanvas`? Best show a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: @mfitzp I've added both `print(np.isnan(self.psi).any())` and `print(np.isinf(self.psi).any())` with outputs `False`, `False`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes, same error for `draw` and `draw_idle`. So `PsiCanvas` is actually showing a plot within a tab of a subwindow within my main GUI window... I can try to put a few more structural hints in my initial comment though.

Comment: I mean, `self.canvas` is a widget, which needs to be added to a layout of your Qt application to show up. Where do you do that?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest totally right - it got deleted by accident when I edited the post earlier; it's back in there now

Comment: @ees thanks. It's also possible for `numpy` to geenerate `inf` values working on large numbers. Grasping at straws but re: Python versions, can you check both version numbers + check `sys.maxint`.

Comment: @mfitzp thanks for the continued help here; for Linux: `sys.version` = 2.7.15 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default) [GCC 7.3.0], `sys.maxint`=9223372036854775807...... For macOS: `sys.version` = 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)], `sys.maxint`=9223372036854775807

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'd be perfectly happy with just suppressing this error; is that an option for this scenario?

Comment: We would need to find out why this error occurs to be able to suppress it. But once we know why it occurs, we could as well just fix it. The problem is that I cannot reproduce this. If you can provide a [mcve] and state the version of matplotlib you're using, I could investigate further.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm working on a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example now

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest when I made a minimal example, the problem went away! So I think this definitely has to do with the competing GUI tabs - there are numerous plots active within each class, all defined via self.ax or self.axes, etc. Could this be an interference between these plots? Also, the warning says `ax_scale = self.axes.bbox.size`, but I'm using `self.ax` for my 3d plot - shouldn't the warning be saying that instead?

Comment: The error says `self.axes` because that is how your 3D axes is called internally within the matplotlib code. A minimal example is the shortest code *that reproduces* the issue, so you apparently took aways too much of it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ok, i've made the M.C.V. example and edited my post above. it seems to be a direct issue between the 2d and 3d axes co-existing on the same subwindow at the same time (but not when either is isolated and run alone).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, so I need to continue guessing... does removing the line `self.figure.set_tight_layout(True)` change anything?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm still getting the error with that removed.

Comment: Further ideas: (1) Did you ever try to remove the line `self.canvas.draw_idle()` completely? (2) Did you try to move the axes creation *after* `self.setLayout...`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've commented out both `draw_idle()` statements and still see the error. I then separately tried moving the axes creation on both classes and again got the error. I've solved this by way of a few tricks to ensure only the currently "seen" tab plots any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The solution here is to simply remove the toolbars - apparently there is some background competition going on between 2d and 3d toolbars being active at the same time (but not for 2d and 2d toolbars)... weird. I'm leaving my other response present below this one, in case anyone runs into something similar where such a workaround might be helpful.

---

Here's the workaround for this issue below; please see the comments `NEW` for everything that was needed for the fix. Basically, this error was happening when both matplotlib's 2d and 3d axes were needed at the same time (albeit on two separate tabs). Now, each plot is constructed live upon tab click.

```
import sys, os
pyDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) #python file location

from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
#matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1
import matplotlib.path as pltPath
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib import rc
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


class P4(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(P4, self).__init__(parent)
        P4.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        P4.layout.setContentsMargins(20,20,20,20)
        P4.layout.setSpacing(10)

        P4.button_pic1 = QtGui.QPushButton('View Plots', self)
        P4.button_pic1.clicked.connect(self.RC_vid1)
        P4.layout.addWidget(P4.button_pic1, 2, 8, 1, 1)
        P4.button_pic1.show()

    def RC_vid1(self):

        global PrD_window
        try:
            PrD_window.close()
        except:
            pass

        PrD_window = PrD_Viz()
        PrD_window.show()

################################################################################

class PrD_Viz(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    currentTab = 0 #NEW

    def __init__(self):
        super(PrD_Viz, self).__init__()
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        vid_tab2 = ManifoldCanvas(self)
        vid_tab3 = PsiCanvas(self)
        global vid_tabs
        vid_tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        vid_tabs.addTab(vid_tab2, 'Plot 1')
        vid_tabs.addTab(vid_tab3, 'Plot 2')


        style = """QTabWidget::tab-bar{
                alignment: center;
                }"""
        self.setStyleSheet(style)
        self.setCentralWidget(vid_tabs)
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal) #freezes out parent window

        if PrD_Viz.currentTab == 1: #NEW
            vid_tabs.setCurrentIndex(1) #NEW
        #NEW:
        vid_tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.onTabChange) #signal for tabs changed via direct click

        self.show()
    #NEW:
    def onTabChange(self, i):
        if i == 0:
            PrD_Viz.currentTab = 0
            self.initUI()
        elif i == 1:
            PrD_Viz.currentTab = 1
            self.initUI()


class ManifoldCanvas(QtGui.QDialog):
    pts_orig = []

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ManifoldCanvas, self).__init__(parent)

        if PrD_Viz.currentTab == 0: #NEW
            self.figure = Figure(dpi=200)
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
            self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

            x=[1,5,9,8]
            y=[2,6,10,11]

            ManifoldCanvas.pts_orig = zip(x,y)
            for i in ManifoldCanvas.pts_orig:
                x,y = i
                self.ax.scatter(x,y,s=1,c='#1f77b4')

            self.canvas.draw_idle()

            layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
            layout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
            layout.addWidget(self.toolbar, 0,0,1,5)
            layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 1,0,1,5)

            self.setLayout(layout)

class PsiCanvas(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PsiCanvas, self).__init__(parent)

        if PrD_Viz.currentTab == 1: #NEW

            self.psi1 = [10,11,12]
            self.psi2 = [24,19,18]
            self.psi3 = [99,90, 105]

            # create canvas and plot data:
            self.figure = Figure(dpi=200)
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
            self.ax = Axes3D(self.figure)
            self.ax.mouse_init()

            self.ax.scatter(self.psi1, self.psi2, self.psi3, label='psi_dif', linewidths= .5, edgecolors='k', c='#d62728') #C3

            self.canvas.draw_idle() #refresh canvas

            layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
            layout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
            layout.addWidget(self.toolbar, 0,0,1,4)
            layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 1,0,4,4)

            self.setLayout(layout)


################################################################################
# overhead GUI control: 

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        tab4 = P4(self)

        global tabs
        tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        tabs.resize(250,150)

        tabs.addTab(tab4, 'Eigenfunctions')

        self.setCentralWidget(tabs)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think the drawback here is that you recreate the plot each time the tab is activated. You probably want to check if that spills the memory, if the old plots aren't garbage collected. In any case if this is indeed the solution, you could also try to set a specific figure size from the start, like `self.figure = Figure(dpi=200, figsize=(3,2))`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm not super delighted with this solution either. There's something weird going on with the 2d and 3d axes competing that this is not addressing (just avoiding). I'll keep thinking on it.

Comment: No there is no competition between 2d and 3d axes. Did you try `figsize=(3,2)`? Does it work or not?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest if you mean to test without my `currentTab` change, setting `figsize` still produces the error. If to test within the `currentTab` change, I tried placing the `figsize` above the `if PrD_Viz.currentTab ==` statement, but it still has to reload the data each time... with some strange/dramatic window resizing for the 1st second or two on the new tab.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. So the problem is clearly that at the moment the figure is first drawn, its size is 0. So one would try to either deferring the first draw to a later point in the program (after the Qt window has been set up), or to make sure the figure size is never 0. But it seems all obvious ideas for either are not successful.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest wow, I think I just stumbled upon the cause of this error by accident... I commented out all references to the toolbar, and everything is working great. For multiple 2d plots on these tabs, those toolbars caused no issue, but the second a 3d toolbar meshed with a 2d toolbar, it appears to have disrupted something. Thanks again for all of your help here!!